# Can't access properties of JSON object from YQL statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, properties, yql

I have a callback function which is executed when I return from making a YQL statement:

```
function cbfunc(json)
{ 
   if (json.query.count)
   { 
      var data = json.query.results.json;
      $("#output").append(data.raw[0]["176932931"].name);
   }
```

This is the JSON object that I'm working with:
http://www.easports.com/iframe/fifa14proclubs/api/platforms/PS4/clubs/51694/members

I'm getting the result of the json and assigning it to the **data** variable. However, when I try to access the data variable (data.raw[0]["176932931"].name), it's giving me the following error: data.raw[0] is undefined.

This is what is returned when I console.log(json):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew7u9.png

This is what is returned when I console.log(data);
https://i.stack.imgur.com/46C4w.png

**HOWEVER**, when I assign the JSON string straight to the data variable, it works correctly, and I'm able to access properties of the object with no errors:

```
var data = {"raw":[{"176932931":{"name":"Shipdawg","blazeId":176932931,"clubStatus":0,"onlineStatus":0,"nucleusId":2266699357,"personaName":"Shipdawg"},"182141183":{"name":"Beks8","blazeId":182141183,"clubStatus":0,"onlineStatus":0,"nucleusId":2272736228,"personaName":"Beks8"},"219929617":{"name":"ChelseaFC_26","blazeId":219929617,"clubStatus":0,"onlineStatus":0,"nucleusId":2304510098,"personaName":"ChelseaFC_26"},"457588267":{"name":"Lazy__Rich","blazeId":457588267,"clubStatus":0,"onlineStatus":0,"nucleusId":2495578386,"personaName":"Lazy__Rich"},"517570695":{"name":"x0__andrew__0x","blazeId":517570695,"clubStatus":0,"onlineStatus":1,"nucleusId":2549150176,"personaName":"x0__andrew__0x"},"912396727":{"name":"mizz00-","blazeId":912396727,"clubStatus":0,"onlineStatus":1,"nucleusId":1000118566560,"personaName":"mizz00-"},"915144354":{"name":"MisterKanii","blazeId":915144354,"clubStatus":2,"onlineStatus":0,"nucleusId":2281969661,"personaName":"MisterKanii"}}]};
```

With this change, I get a slightly different object back when I console.log(data):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hLvr.png

But I can't use that as a solution since the data variable will be different depending on my YQL statement.

So the question is, how am I meant to access the properties of the first object? This one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/46C4w.png

I've looked all over SO and Google and I just can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON object you are getting back from that first link appears to be different from what displays from your `console.log` statements.

Specifically, in the example from [EASports](http://www.easports.com/iframe/fifa14proclubs/api/platforms/PS4/clubs/51694/members), the `raw` property is an array of length one containing a JSON object, yet what you seem to be dealing with is simply the JSON object itself.

To get you existing code working, you could do something like:

```
$("#output").append(data.raw["_12396727"].name);
```

In a more general sense, the use of [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) that @Neversay is proposing would allow you to iterate over the results contained in `data.raw`. So to access the underlying JSON object literal, you could use something like:

```
var keys = Object.keys(data.raw);

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var obj = data.raw[keys[i]];
    console.log(obj.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var key0 = Object.keys(data.raw)[0];
var name = data.raw[key0].name; ......
```

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on this and give me a working example? How do I access the nested JSON objects? eg. data.raw["176932931"].name

Answer (score 0):

Interest, the result from EAsport is a list contains one object. But after being processed by YQL, the raw becomes a object, not an arrow anymore......